# JSON from nested query

Tags: soql, json

I've got this query:

SELECT name, (SELECT From__c, To__c FROM Trip__r) FROM Account limit 1

```
[ {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/001b000000HZ"
  },
  "Name" : "Adam II",
  "Trip__r" : {
    "totalSize" : 2,
    "done" : true,
    "records" : [ {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Trip__c",
        "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Trip__c/a00b000000AOj"
      },
      "To__c" : "2013-11-27T15:15:00.000+0000",
      "Id" : "a00b000000AOj",
      "Car__c" : "001b000000HZ",
      "From__c" : "2013-11-25T15:15:00.000+0000"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Trip__c",
        "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Trip__c/a00b000000A"
      },
      "To__c" : "2013-11-28T20:58:00.000+0000",
      "Id" : "a00b000000AOlR",
      "Car__c" : "001b000000HZp",
      "From__c" : "2013-11-27T20:58:00.000+0000"
    } ]
  },
  "Id" : "001b000000HZp"
} ]
```

But, I need to get rid this part

```
   "Trip__r" : {
    "totalSize" : 2,
    "done" : true,
```

So it looks like

```
[ {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/001b000000HZ"
  },
  "Name" : "Adam II",
    "records" : [ {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Trip_c",
        "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Trip_c/a00b000000AOj"
      },
      "To_c" : "2013-11-27T15:15:00.000+0000",
      "Id" : "a00b000000AOj",
      "Car_c" : "001b000000HZ",
      "From_c" : "2013-11-25T15:15:00.000+0000"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Trip_c",
        "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Trip_c/a00b000000A"
      },
      "To_c" : "2013-11-28T20:58:00.000+0000",
      "Id" : "a00b000000AOlR",
      "Car_c" : "001b000000HZp",
      "From_c" : "2013-11-27T20:58:00.000+0000"
    } ],
  "Id" : "001b000000HZp"
} ]
```

I tried to look around wrappers, deserialisations, but still can't understand them! Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Try http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/. It'll generate Apex that parses the JSON into a class.

Comment: I seriously don't get the purpose of that app. It puts everything into one great string - so what? For my testing I've put the string into VF page and parsed with JS, just to see where the snags were. Now I need to adjust the JSON output a bit.

Comment: j2a builds Apex Code that you can copy-paste into your org to serialize/deserialize the JSON strings (it's not perfect, though, so you may need to tweak the results). It also includes a test method (that was the great JSON string you saw).

Comment: I kinda forgot to mention that I am serialising my SOQL output. `List<Account> accounts = [SELECT name, (SELECT From_c, To_c FROM Trip__r) FROM Account limit 1];`
        return JSON.serializePretty(accounts)

Comment: @MikeChale seems like the issue is really that subqueries don't serialize well, since under the hood they're a query locator rather than a full result set.

Comment: I have used regex to solve the issue. However, I want to convert the date time into special format. I'm thinking using regex again, but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Was trying to write wrapper class to put everything into list and then serialise. But before that I need to convert the to and from fields into different datetime format. The closest I've found is [this solution](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13522/nested-soql-query), however it's not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

trip__c extends completely like :

```
"Trip__r" : {
    "totalSize" : 2,
    "done" : true,
    "records" : [ {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Trip__c",
        "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Trip__c/a00b000000AOj"
      },
      "To__c" : "2013-11-27T15:15:00.000+0000",
      "Id" : "a00b000000AOj",
      "Car__c" : "001b000000HZ",
      "From__c" : "2013-11-25T15:15:00.000+0000"
    }
```

you need to completely remove this part.

1> convert this list to JSON string using

```
String str=JSON.stringify(list);
```

2>perform string manipulation on this string to remove unnecessry part.
3>convert the string back to list object using JSON.desrialize()

ex :

```
list<account> acclist=(list<Account>)JSON.deserialize(str,list<Account>.class);
```

and one more thing that can be done is, you can look at documentation for JSON and JSONParser class that might be helpful.