# Map all data columns of a SOQL response

Tags: apex, soql, map

I want to know if it is possible through a map or some form of multidimentional List type to contain more than 2 parameters. For example I have a nice SOQL here that returns a column for Contact, Quote, and CampaignMember (each row tranversed by ContactId)

```
Map<Contact, Quote, CampaignMember> masterMap = [
SELECT 
    Id, 
    (SELECT Id, Name FROM Quotes), 
    (SELECT Id FROM CampaignMembers) 
FROM Contact 
WHERE Id IN :contact_list
]
```

How do I store the result from a SOQL like this in a way I can use? My only other alternative I can foresee myself is to have two separate queries (see below) which I'm hoping is avoidable.

```
Map<Contact,Quote> quoteMap = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Quotes) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contact_list]

Map<Contact,CampaignMember> membersMap = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM CampaignMembers) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contact_list]
```

Comment: I know you can do something like this Map<Id,List<Id>>, not sure if it helps but you might find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I found a solution that works, thanks to [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/13523/10834)

```
Map<Id, List<Quote>> QuoteMap = new Map<Id,List<Quote>>();
Map<Id, List<CampaignMember>> CampaignMemberMap = new Map<Id,List<CampaignMember>>();

List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Quotes), (SELECT Id FROM CampaignMembers) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contact_list];
for(Contact c : contacts){
    QuoteMap.put(c.Id, c.getSObjects('Quotes')); // put the Contact Quotes in a map by ContactId
    CampaignMemberMap.put(c.Id, c.CampaignMembers); // put the Contact CampaignMembers in a map by ContactId without using getSObjects method as mentioned in the comments
}
```

Comment: No need to cache the results! You can just take the first two lines of that for loop and merge them into the corresponding `put` call. e.g. `QuoteMap.put(contact.Id, contact.getSObjects('Quotes'));`

Comment: Technically don't even need the getSObjects part since you have them declared, i.e. can just do `QuoteMap.put(c.Id, c.Quotes);`

Comment: When would I need getSObjects then because I tried to remove them from the SOQL but got an error that I was attempting a field that was not accessible from my result?