# Iterate through Map with a List of sObjects

Tags: apex, map

After resolving my issue [posted here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64732/map-all-data-columns-of-a-soql-response), I was finally able to get a `Map<Id,List<Quote>>` variable like I needed, but now I can't seem to iterate through the variable. I have tried things like this:

```
for(Contact cid : quotes.keyset()){
    System.debug(quotes.get(cid));
}
```

> **Results:** [ERROR] Incompatible key type SOBJECT:Contact for MAP>

AND

```
for(List<Quote> q : quotes.values()){
    System.debug(q);
}
```

> **Results:** System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your key in the map is of type Id, so your first for loop should be on Id:

```
for (Id recordId : quotes.keySet())
{}
```

Then your value for each of the keys (IDs) is a list of quotes, meaning the second for loop will be on the Quote object:

```
for (Id recordId : quotes.keySet())
{
    for (Quote quoteRecord : quotes.get(recordId))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you want to go through all the quotes regardless of the IDs, you can do this:

```
for (List <Quote> quoteList : quotes.values())
{
    for (Quote quoteRecord : quoteList)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to iterate over a Map and do some logic for specific keys use this

```
Map<Integer, String> m= new Map<Integer, String> {1=> 'a', 2=>'b'};

Integer[] n = new Integer[]{};
for (Integer i : m.keySet())
{
    n.add(i);
}
Integer j = 0;
for (String s : m.values())
{        
    if (n[j]== 1) {  // 1 here is value of the key, you can use your value

        //DO something
        system.debug(n[j]+' '+s);    j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an example of what NOT to do. This is wrong in so many ways. Especially in the unneeded code if one was to take your approach as the iteration on the keys is complete waste